# F# unique overload method

Tags: generics, f#, types

How am I able to call send(a:'T []) in such a type?

```
type Test() =
  member o.send(value:'T) = 4
  member o.send(values:'T []) = 5

let test = Test()
let b = test.send [|4|]
```

When I do that, I obtain

```
A unique overload for method 'Send' could not be determined based on type information 
prior to this program point. The available overloads are shown below...
```

The point is the MPI.NET has got exactly this method called Send and I am not able to send an array into it.

Thank you,
Oldrich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
type Test() =
  member o.send(a:'T) = 4
  member o.send(a:'T []) = 5

let test = Test()
let b = test.send<int>([|4|] : _[]) // 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, F# can't determine if your T is an int, or an array of ints, so the only way I can see to work round your problem is like this

```
let b = test.send<int> [|4|]
```

or this

```
let b = test.send<int array> [|4|]
```

Comment: At last, an F# question I can answer. It's been a long time!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. It does not however work as expected. When I run let b = test.send<int array> [|4|] I get 4 as the result and I should get 5.

Comment: That was my first reaction too, but if **T is an `int array`**, then passing `[|4|]` will invoke the first overload.

Comment: @Oldrich, sorry, I read your question backwards - my answer shows alternatives for calling both overloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using pattern matching on types:

```
type MyTest() =
    member this.Send (a : obj)  = 
        match a with
        | :? System.Collections.IEnumerable -> 5
        | _ -> 4
```

This will match on any `Seq` type in F# (array, list, seq). Once you have the right match is is usually easier to implement private functions for the specific type.